# JQuery Lightbox 2 Plugin problem

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, lightbox, lightbox2

I'm working on a gallery, which use jQuery Lighbox 2 ([plugin page](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)). I have the problem, that the navigation entries are also visible, when an image is selected ([see example here](http://bufka.ath.cx/Quelle/galerie/galerie1.html)). For the navigation i'm using css menu. Can someone  tell me, how to make the enties invisible, when an image was selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `z-index` to 5000. in the file lightbox.css

Example:

```
#lightbox {
    left:0;
    line-height:0;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    z-index:5000; /* move the lightbox above all other elements */
}
```